# how to use WebBrowserReadyState for Gecko webbrowser in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, browser, gecko

How to use **"WebBrowserReadyState"** for **"Gecko webbrowser"** or how to wait till it loads web page completely.

i am trying to make a web page reloader that should reload a web page after it loads completely.

i have achieved this task by using **"default .net webbeowser component"** but i want to use **"gecko webbrowser component"** instead of **"default webbrowser component"** but i don't know how to use **"WebBrowserReadyState"** for **"Gecko webbrowser component"**

**below is my code that worked for default webbrowser component:**

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
           {
               webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
           }
    }
```

please tell me how to use **"webBrowserReadyState.Complete for Gecko"** because this code don't work for Gecko

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method

```
    private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // here you can perform the actions you wants to do after page loads
    }
```

And when your page contains more `ajax` or `javascript` files to run , you can check the following conditions like , `geckobrowser1.IsBusy` & `geckobrowser.IsAjaxBusy` .